# Web Service query not showing strings in array

Tags: c#, web-services

Hi I have a problem when trying to return a query´s contents (strings) as a arraylist. I have managed with one of my queries but I'm not able to reproduce it in another method. (I have a EmplAbsence class)

Webservice method 1:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<EmplAbsence> getEmplAbsence()
{
    List<EmplAbsence> emplAbsence = new List<EmplAbsence>();

    try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();

        string queryEmplAbsence = "select [First Name],[Last Name] from [CRONUS Sverige AB$Employee] where No_ in (select  [Employee No_] from [CRONUS Sverige AB$Employee Absence] where Description='Sjuk'and [From Date] between '2004-01-01' and '2004-12-31')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryEmplAbsence, sqlConn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            EmplAbsence ez = new EmplAbsence(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
            Console.WriteLine(ez);
            emplAbsence.Add(ez);
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
    return emplAbsence;
}

public class EmplAbsence
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;

    public EmplAbsence()
    {
    }
    public EmplAbsence(string firstname, string lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

The query works in SQL Server Manager but it doesn't seem to print out the strings designated. I need it to look like this to be able to use it in a Java client application:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated! It's probably a small mistake but I've been grinding my head with this for quite some time.

Comment: may be problem in the constructor of EmplAbsence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After verifying that your constructor is setting the values correctly, you need to specify which members of your class you want to serialize using the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract(Name="MostSick")]
public class EmplAbsence
{

  [DataMember]
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

and return an `Array` instead of a `List<T>` in your service method.

`return emplAbsence.ToArray();`